# What effect does a const have for effect before the return type in a function?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
const string getConstString()
{
    return "MyConstString";
}

int main()
{
    string str1 = getConstString();
    cout << str1 << endl;
}
```

What effect does the const keyword have here?

Comment: Re the duplicate, the accepted answer there, by James Kanze, is incorrect.

Comment: yes and yes, prefixing a function definition means the object returned will be const. Meaning, if you want to store it, you will have to store it in a const object.

Comment: `void main` has always been invalid in both C and C++. Please don't post code with `void main`, since it misleads beginners and makes it more difficult to test your code by direct copy and paste. FTFY.

Comment: Sorry, James' answer is **not** incorrect as I wrote. It's merely old and therefore incomplete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One notable effect is that you can't *move* from a `const` result.

Before C++ gained direct support for move semantics in C++11, a not uncommon advice was to make return types `const` in order force client code to only use the result in meaningful ways, as a value (and not as a mutable object).

After C++11 the advice is the opposite: don't make a return value `const`, because that prevents moving.

---

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

auto m() -> string { return {}; }
auto c() -> const string { return {}; }

void check( string&& ) { cout << "mutable\n"; }
void check( string const&& ) { cout << "const\n"; }

auto main()
    -> int
{
    check( m() );
    check( c() );
}
```

This outputs

```
mutable
const
```

… showing that the `const` on the result for function `c`, is very much noticeable to the calling code.

---

With `int` instead of `string` the output is instead 2 × “`mutable`”, showing a subtle and surprising difference in treatment of built-in types and class types: that top-level `const` is ignored for a result that is of a built-in type such as `int`.

*C++11 §3.10/4 (basic.lval/4):*

> **”** Class prvalues can have cv-qualified types; non-class prvalues always have cv-unqualified types.

It's worth noting that this is a rule for *the type of prvalue expressions*, and not a rewrite rule for function declarations like the decay to pointer type of an array or function type formal argument. I.e., the type of the function is not affected. The `const` is there still in the type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>      // std::is_same
using namespace std;

#define STATIC_ASSERT( e ) static_assert( e, #e " <- is needed." )

auto c() -> const int{ return {}; }

auto main()
    -> int
{
    // Function type:
    STATIC_ASSERT(( is_same<decltype( c ), auto()->const int>::value ));
    STATIC_ASSERT(( not is_same<decltype( c ), auto()->int>::value ));

    // prvalue type:
    STATIC_ASSERT(( is_same<decltype( c() ), int>::value ));
    STATIC_ASSERT(( not is_same<decltype( c() ), int const>::value ));
}
```

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: No, copy elision works just fine anyway.

Comment: Can you explain prevents moving.

Comment: @Niklas moving from a temporary implies modifying that temporary (in order to signal you stole it's resources). You can't modify a const object. Thus const temporaries can't be moved from.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf If I remember correctly the rule is that top most const is ignored in the return type if the type is a built-in type (and not a reference). Is that correct?

Comment: @bolov: I think that's correct. But not sure where the standard says that.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf https://godbolt.org/g/a38UJW

Comment: @bolov: Thanks! I updated the answer. Now to find the standardese...

Comment: @bolov: Found it, updated the answer, learned something today too, still alive. :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf great!! Good job! Couldn't have been easy to find. Good to know the real rule.